# VBA to update pivot tables after data is populated

Tags: excel, refresh, pivot-table, vba

I'm facing a problem where VBA does not update pivot tables after all the tasks are done. Please see the code below. It should update all the Pivot tables in every single worksheet. It seems like the excel is ignoring the last bit of the code and not running it at all?

```
    Sub update_data()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    Const raw_data_1 As String = "raw_data_1"
    Const raw_data_2 As String = "raw_data_2"
    Const shUpdate As String = "ORP"

OPTIMISE (True)

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(raw_data_1).Cells.ClearContents

    If Worksheets(shUpdate).FilterMode = True Then
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(shUpdate)
        .Range("A2:F" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .ShowAllData
    End With
    Else
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(shUpdate)
        .Range("A2:F" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    End With
    End If

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(raw_data_1).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://www.link/", Destination _
        :=Worksheets(raw_data_1).Range("A1"))
        .Name = "packageSummary"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = """ec_table"""
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(raw_data_1)
        .Range(.Range("A3"), .Range("A3").End(xlDown)).copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets(shUpdate).Range("A2")
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(shUpdate)
        .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns _
            Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
            :="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(raw_data_1)
        .Range("D3:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row).copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets(shUpdate).Range("D2")
        .Range("F3:F" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row).copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets(shUpdate).Range("E2")
        .Range("G3:G" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row).copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets(shUpdate).Range("F2")
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(raw_data_2).Cells.ClearContents

   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(raw_data_2).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
      "URL;https://link/", _
         Destination:=Worksheets(raw_data_2).Range("A1"))

      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
      .SaveData = True
   End With

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.RefreshTable
        Next pt
    Next ws

OPTIMISE False

End Sub
```

Comment: what line is being ignored? When you step through the code?

Comment: For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets if you scroll down at the bottom of the code you will find the code which should update every single pivot table in workbook

Comment: What does `OPTIMISE` do?

Comment: @Martin how is your `PivotTable` suppose to be updated with the updated data received from the `QueryTables` ? You need to set up your `PivotCache` to the `SourceData` (in your case it's a `QueryTable`), and then you can use `pt.PivotCache.Refresh`

Comment: As @ShaiRado says ^ Or, if your pivot tables are linked to your "ORP" sheet, is your problem simply that they are only linked to data in that sheet which is not being changed?  (E.g. maybe linked to the first 100 rows, but you are now copying more data which extends to row 101+)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I woudl try an alternative approach to the pivot tables -

```
  ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

or if that does not work, try looping through all the pivot table -

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        pt.PivotCache.Refresh
    Next pt
Next ws
```